# Using 'dict set' command with multiple keys and values in Tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I am trying to play around with dictionaries and I cam across `dict set` command. Using this command, I able to set new value to existing key.

When I tried to set the values for more than one keys, then I am getting `"missing value to go with key"`

I have tried the commands in 2 ways,

```
#keys list and then values list
dict set userinfo name age VIGNESH 23
#key and value pair
dict set userinfo name VIGNESH age 23
```

I have looked into the man page of `dict set` and found the following

```
dict set dictionaryVariable key ?key ...? value
    This operation takes the name of a variable containing a dictionary value and places an updated dictionary value in that variable containing a mapping from the given key to the given value. When multiple keys are present, this operation creates or updates a chain of nested dictionaries.
```

This is what I am trying

```
% set userinfo { name DINESH age 24 dob {16/05/1990} state Chennai }  
 name DINESH age 24 dob {16/05/1990} state Chennai 
% dict get $userinfo
name DINESH age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Chennai
% dict set userinfo state Madurai
name DINESH age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Madurai
% dict get $userinfo
name DINESH age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Madurai
% dict set userinfo name age VIGNESH 23
missing value to go with key
% dict set userinfo name VIGNESH age 23
missing value to go with key
%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use multiple keys, it means that you are trying to access a second, third, etc of nested dicts. Consider:

```
% set userinfo [dict create user {name DINESH surname A} age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Chennai]
user {name DINESH surname A} age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Chennai
% dict set userinfo user surname B
user {name DINESH surname B} age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Chennai
```

As you can see, the above will change the value of the key `surname` within the higher level value of the key `user`, into `B`.

Or if you prefer, first check the value of `user` (which gives a dict), then (from that dict) `surname` and change that value.

Note that the documentation mentions nested dictionaries and a *single* value.

Comment: Great. Got it. Does this mean we can set one value at a time with `dict set`  ?

Comment: @Dinesh You can use `dict map` to iterate over the key/value pairs. It's usage a bit like a `for` loop and you can use `if` and `break` for example to ensure the correct key/value pairs are being changed.

Comment: `dict for` is for plain iteration. `dict map` is for transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
dict with userinfo {
    set name VIGNESH
    set age 23
}
```

The command-subcommand `dict with` maps the values of a dictionary to variables named after the keys, and evaluates a script body. If that script changes the values of the variables, the values in the dictionary will be changed as well. Note that the variables will continue to exist after the script has been evaluated (but changing their values will no longer have any effect on the values in the dictionary), and any variables with the same names will be overwritten.

For a nested dictionary as in Jerry's example, you can specify a chain of keys to get to the level you want:

```
set userinfo [dict create user {name DINESH surname A} age 24 dob 16/05/1990 state Chennai]

dict with userinfo user {
    set name VIGNESH
    set surname B
}
```

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)